# How to configure Guice modules in parallel?

Tags: java, guice

Background: My codebase has a lot of modules and, according to some profiling, creating the Guice injector takes a significant amount of time. This is almost certainly due to the massive amount of modules and the existence of a few modules that take a long time to configure. In theory I can produce 2+ lists of modules that can be configured separately.

Is there any way to parallelize the configuration of these modules?

For example, if there's a way to combine or merge two Guice injectors I could create them in separate threads then join them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `Concurrent Singleton` library from Netflix, it allows you to lazy load the Guice modules in concurrent fashion.

https://github.com/Netflix/governator/wiki/Concurrent-Singleton

> Guice’s default Singleton scope synchronizes all object creation on a
>   single lock (see here). It does this to avoid deadlocks with circular
>   dependencies. Governator adds the FineGrainedLazySingleton annotation
>   that locks on the Guice Key so that multiple singletons can be created
>   concurrently. Circular dependencies are rare so
>   FineGrainedLazySingleton risks deadlocks in those situations for the
>   benefit of better concurrency.
>
> A class annotated with FineGrainedLazySingleton will be
>
> 1. lazily created (like Lazy Singleton)
> 2. created by the FineGrainedLazySingletonScope which synchronizes on
>      the Guice Key instead of InternalInjectorCreator.class)
> 3. able to be created alongside other FineGrainedLazySingleton in
>      different threads

Comment: This was a promising lead, but it turns out that the those Governator annotations have been deprecated for various reasons. I was unable to speed anything up using those tags or the suggested workarounds